# React native expo iOS cannot ask for background location on physical device

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation, expo, user-permissions

I am trying to get background permissions using expo Location. This works on android and on an iOS simulator but not on a physical iOS device.

```
const askLoc = async () => {
    const requestForeground = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (requestForeground.status === 'granted') {
      const requestBackground = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (requestBackground.status === 'granted') {
        console.log('background location granted');
      }
    }
  };
```

This is what my `app.json` looks like.

```
"ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to send pictures or create a new profile photo.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "User can download documents that were previously uploaded by company",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "User can upload Photos/Documents to be seen by his/her company",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "Location is shared with users company while he/she is completing a task/job.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Location is shared with users company while he/she is completing a task/job.",
        "NSUserActivityTypes": ["INSendMessageIntent", "INStartCallIntent"],
        "UIBackgroundModes": ["location", "fetch"],
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some factors you need to consider to debug the issue:

1. Make sure that location access enables.
   `await Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync()`
2. There's a probability that, recently, you deny location permission
   definitively. `requestForeground.status` will always resolve as `denied`

Detect if `requestForeground.canAskAgain` set to `true` otherwise user has already denied this permission and you can open device setting and user grant that permission manually.

Here permission response type definition

```
export interface PermissionResponse {
  status: PermissionStatus;
  expires: PermissionExpiration;
  granted: boolean;
  canAskAgain: boolean;
}
```